# Python save colorchooser

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have this paint like program and have a button where if i click it, I can pick a color. However I can't seem to figure out how to save that option and change the color of the cells I'm painting. I have the default painted color as "black" and the outline is also black, the values should change to the ones the def color saves. Please help, this is my first time doing something like this.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import colorchooser
import tkinter as tk

# root = Tk()


class Grilla:

    colorCelda = "black"
    colorDefault = "white"
    colorBorde = "black"
    bordeDefault = "black"

    def __init__(self, root, master, x, y, size):
        """ Constructor of the object called by Cell(...) """
        self.master = master
        self.abs = x
        self.ord = y
        self.size = size
        self.fill = False

    def switch(self):
        """ Switch if the cell is filled or not. """
        self.fill = not self.fill

    def reset(self):
        """ Clears the cell """
        self.fill = False

    def draw(self):
        # dibujar en el canvas
        if self.master is not None:

            outline = Grilla.colorBorde
            fill = Grilla.colorCelda

            if not self.fill:
                outline = Grilla.bordeDefault
                fill = Grilla.colorDefault

            xmin = self.abs * self.size
            xmax = xmin + self.size
            ymin = self.ord * self.size
            ymax = ymin + self.size

            self.master.create_rectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, fill=fill, outline=outline)


class CellGrilla(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, numFil, numCol, tamGrid, *args, **kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master, width=tamGrid * numCol, height=tamGrid * numFil, *args, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.square_clicked)
        self.cellSize = tamGrid

        self.pen = "draw"

        self._grid = []
        for row in range(numFil):

            line = []
            for column in range(numCol):
                line.append(Grilla(master, self, column, row, tamGrid))

            self._grid.append(line)

        # memorize the cells that have been modified to avoid many switching of state during mouse motion.
        self.switched = []

        self.draw()

    def square_clicked(self, event):
        row, column = self._coordenadas(event)
        cell = self._grid[row][column]
        if self.pen == "draw":
            cell.switch()
        cell.draw()

    def draw(self):
        for row in self._grid:
            for cell in row:
                cell.draw()

    def _coordenadas(self, event):
        # `int(a / b)` is the same as `a // b`
        row = event.y // self.cellSize
        column = event.x // self.cellSize
        return row, column

    def switch_to_draw(self):
        self.pen = "draw"

    def color(self):
        colorSelec = colorchooser.askcolor()[1]

    def DDA(self):
        # DDA algorithm 
        
    def clear(self):
        for row in self._grid:
            for cell in row:
                cell.reset()
                cell.draw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Tk()

    # Tamaño de canvas x tamaño de pixeles
    grid = CellGrilla(app, 75, 75, 10)

    grid.grid(row=1, column=1, rowspan=4, sticky="news")

    colorBoton = Button(app, text="Elegir Color", command=grid.color, height=1, width=30)
    ddaBoton = Button(app, text="DDA", command=grid.DDA, height=1, width=30)
    zoomInBoton = Button(app, text="Zoom in", command=grid.switch_to_draw, height=1, width=30)
    zoomOutBoton = Button(app, text="Zoom out", command=grid.switch_to_draw, height=1, width=30)
    reset_btn = Button(app, text="Borrar", command=grid.clear, height=1, width=30)

    zoomInBoton.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="news")
    zoomOutBoton.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="news")
    colorBoton.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky="news")
    ddaBoton.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky="news")
    reset_btn.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky="news")

    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? You're using the colors `fill` and `outline` when you create the rectangles. Have you verified those values have been changed to the result from the color chooser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update `Grilla.colorCelda` if you have chosen a color:

```py
class CellGrilla(Canvas):
    ...
    def color(self):
        colorSelec = colorchooser.askcolor()[1]
        if colorSelec:
            Grilla.colorCelda = colorSelec
```